# Auto Complete Box in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am making a simple application and I would like to perform an action that suggests code as you type, just like other programming languages do. Examples of where this has been used is within programming language software such as ... **visual basic, Xcode, Small Basic, etc**. My application would evolve around a `RichTextBox` and as you type, a box would appear below showing suggestion's of words. If you are still confused with my question see images below, showing examples from **Visual Basic** and **Small Basic**

**Small Basic**

[image: Small Basic]

**Visual Basic**

.[image: Visual Basic]

These drop down suggestion box can also be accessed with **CTRL + SPACE**

I know this is quite a complicated and longwinded question but any suggestions on how I can create this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. However the project is programmed in c# instead of vb.net so I simply followed the instructions online you can find the solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365974/Autocomplete-Menu)